eclipse "Compile with javacc" just does nothing
I haven't used javaCC for several years. Now (year 2024) that I try it again with the lates tools, "Compile with javacc" just does nothing: no *.java files generated, no error messages, just, plain, nothing.
It is possible to call javacc on my (old) *.jj and *.jjt files and I get my *.java files (where eclipse complains later about some errors, very probably to the fact that many things have changed by the time they were working, some 5-15 years ago).
One additional thing to mention is that the standard example file MyNewGrammer.jjt produces (via shell command "javacc MyNewGrammer.jjt") java files where jjtThis is unknown ... straight from the automatically generated jjt).
I also dimly remember that *.jjt was converted to *.jj first, but I see no trace of it now.
What's wrong? Are there currently know issues or common pitfalls?

helper@gg$ javac -version
javac 11.0.24
helper@gg$ javacc -version
7.0.12
helper@gg$ javacc -verbose MyNewGrammar.jjt 
Java Compiler Compiler Version 7.0.12 (Parser Generator)
(type "javacc" with no arguments for help)
Warning: Bad option "-verbose" will be ignored.
Reading from file MyNewGrammar.jjt . . .
File "TokenMgrError.java" is being rebuilt.
File "ParseException.java" is being rebuilt.
File "Token.java" is being rebuilt.
File "SimpleCharStream.java" is being rebuilt.
Parser generated successfully.
helper@gg$ 


The tools I use are those coming with eclipse and what I got from "The Marketplace" searching for JavaCC.
Eclipse tells me it was "JavaCC Eclipse Plug-in Feature" (version 1.6.1):
JavaCC & JTB editor, views, nature and builder which process .jj, .jjt & .jtb files and integrate with Eclipse's incremental build system, for head (and headless) builds.
Must be installed for head builds (ie with the UI). Will allow headless builds.
Compatible with Eclipse Neon+ (4.6+) and Java 1.8+. Embeds some versions of JavaCC and JTB jars.

You are talking about the JavaCC Eclipse Plug-in, right? If so, please update your question with the link. This plugins is not part of an official Eclipse IDE package; you got it via the Eclipse Marketplace from https://eclipse-javacc.sourceforge.net/.

See Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details for what you have installed. The latest version of the JavaCC Eclipse Plug-in is 1.6.1.

@GyroGearloose Please do not add the answer to the question body. Instead, post an actual answer.

@Progman the text you deleted was not an answer but a additional information. Packing that into an answer would be equally wrong. So, I know it, it's gone, and, why should I care about others?

OS
Linux: Ubuntu
JDK 17
Please install your own JDK, recommended version: JDK 17.
Download Eclipse IDE: eclipse-jee-2024-06
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2024-06/r

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers

Linux x86_64
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2024-06/R/eclipse-jee-2024-06-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz



UNZIP eclipse-jee-2024-06-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
Run Eclipse
cd eclipse-jee-2024-06-R-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse
./eclipse

Config Workspace Directory:
I use an empty directory WK as the workspace directory.
/your-path/WK

Install JavaCC Eclipse Plug-in
Eclipse Marketplace


Search -> Find , Input: JavaCC

Find: JavaCC Eclipse Plug-in 1.6.1

Click Button: Install


license agreement


I accept the terms of the license agreement
Click Button: Finish



[V] https://eclipse.javacc.source....
Click Button: Trust Selected



[V] x509
Click Button: Trust Selected


Software Updates

Click Button: Restart Now

Create Project

Menu File -> New - Other

Select a wizard

Java Project
Click Button: Next



Project Name: MyJavaCCExample
JRE: JavaSE-17
Click Button: Finish


Open Associated Perspective ?

Click Button: Open Perspective

Create New Folder

MyJavaCCExample -> New -> Folder


Folder Name: outputJavaCC
Click Button: Finish

Add Source Folder


MyJavaCCExample -> Properties



Java Build Path -> Source
Click Button: Add Folder...


Source Folder Selection

outputJavaCC
Click Button: OK



Click Button: Apply and Close

Config JavaCC

JavaCC -> Javacc options

JDK_VERSION: 17
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY: Click Button: Browse...



Select Project MyJavaCCExample/outputJavaCC
Click Button Open



JavaCC options change
Do you want to rebuild the project for options changes to take effect ?

Click Button: Yes

Delete module-info.java


Select MyJavaCCExample -> src -> module-info.java
Click Delete

Create JavaCC jj file

MyJavaCCExample -> src -> New -> File

Create New File

File name: calculator.jj
Click Button: Finish


Use Browser Open https://github.com/gammasoft/gammalang/blob/master/calculator.jj

NOTE: https://github.com/gammasoft/gammalang/tree/master

LICENSE: MIT license

Copy the file content of calculator.jj to our project file calculator.jj


Please note that the JavaCC Console is executed automatically.

MyJavaCCExample -> outputJavaCC -> (default package)
Based on the contents of calculator.jj, Calculator.java and other files are automatically generated.
Run Java Application or Run As (Run Configurations)

MyJavaCCExample -> outputJavaCC -> Calculator.java

Run As -> Java Application

or

MyJavaCCExample -> outputJavaCC -> Calculator.java

Run As -> Run Configurations


Left Tree: Java Application
Right Part:

Name: Calculator

Project: MyJavaCCExample

Main class: Calculator

Click Button: Run


Console

In Console:
Input: 11 + 22 Then Press Enter Key
Then show 33.0

Thank you, I will try to follow your step-by-step guidance. This may take some time. Until recently, I used a local, fixed version of eclipse but latest ubuntu upgrade forced me to use the snap version where the user does not have control of fatal improvements.

Whhhatttt? Deleting module-info? !! OK, I trust you and follow your steps and deffer understanding until later ;-)

It worked except that the Console did not open automatically. I had to modify Calculator.java main with System.out.print("Hello JavaCC\n"); to trigger the Console open. I Still don't know what I had done wrong, as previously it worked out of the box, but now at least I have a working example to build upon.

Your way of doing works, I have not only *jj but also *.jjt files working, but I still have no idea why your way works, and that what I have tried did not. I tried your cure on my old workspace, creating a folder for the output, setting the path in properties->JavaCC, even deleted module-info. As long as I don't understand it, the next update will wreck everything and I'll have to ask again.

(1) module-info.java can be retained, but requirements, opening and other settings must be added in accordance with the rules of Java Module (you must understand the relevant setting rules and knowledge of module-info). (To simplify, I think there is no need to modularize the program, so I deleted module-info.java directly) (2) It is not recommended to modify the java program code generated by jj or jjt, because when you modify jj, the corresponding The new Java code will be regenerated, if the modified Java code will be lost.

(3) To execute the Java program in Eclipse, not xxx.java in any location will be executed, it (JavaCC Output) is The directory must be set as the Source Folder before the Java in the directory will be executed. (This is the knowledge of the Eclipse Java project and has nothing to do with the JavaCC plugin)

(4) Before I reply to your question, I have not come into contact with JavaCC or JavaCC Eclipse Plugin. (5) I installed the JavaCC Eclipse Plugin in the Eclipse Market Place according to your instructions. (6) At the beginning, the JavaCC Eclipse Plugin did not work. It took effect.

(7) Later I found the JavaCC Eclipse Plugin project on SourceForge, which had several pictures of Project Sample. (8) It had a JavaCC setting screen for Eclipse. So I checked the options on the screen and Select the settings and find out the items that may need to be set. (9) It is troublesome to choose a simple and executable jj example of JavaCC. So I found the example on the Internet. It is MIT License. (10) Then proceed Test. That's it.

(11) module-info.java is only available since Java 9. If your project is Java 8, there will be no module-info.java at all. (12) Non-modular Java projects, The default does not need to have module-info.java.

Thank you again. (1) and (2) are understood. (3): I have set this, but with the eclipse version from snap, I didn't get it to work. Probably there is some tiny difference in the setup, if predefined or from my own hands. Something that I have to find out by myself, with try&error.

I tried your advice on a new project in the old workspace, with eclipse from snap. I skipped the steps that were already done, and it works. It still does not work with my old project. The main difference I can see is that the old project is a maven project.

(1) Select your project, -> (Popup Menu) -> Properties (2) Left Project Natures ->  Right, Button Add -> JavaCC Nature

I converted the new project (where javacc was working) to maven project, and it didn't work any more. I removed the maven nature, and it still does not work. Both projects, the old one as well as the on re-converted from maven, both have already JavaCC nature. I deleted it and added it again, but to no avail. I still can have another new project with your steps, and it works. Looks like a problem between maven and eclipse.

I have opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79048128/4142984

I have provided another set of answers for JavaCC Plugin with Maven Project. It also provides complete steps and operation screens.

JavaCC Plugin with Maven Project
Project Tree

Create a Directory : MyJavaCCExampleMaven

MyJavaCCExampleMaven
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        └── jj
            └── calculator.jj

pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-javacc-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-javacc-example</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.encoding>UTF-8</maven.compiler.encoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
    </build>
</project>

jj/calculator.jj
Use Browser Open https://github.com/gammasoft/gammalang/blob/master/calculator.jj
Copy the file content of calculator.jj to our project file calculator.jj

https://github.com/gammasoft/gammalang
LICENSE: MIT license

Eclipse Steps
Select a directory as workspace

create a new directory: WK2
Start Eclipse
Menu File -> Switch Workspace -> Other
Select new directory: WK2

Import Maven Project
Menu File -> Import

Maven -> Existing Maven Projects
Click Button Next

Select Maven Projects
Click Button Browse
Then Select Directory MyJavaCCExampleMaven
Then Click Button Finish

Config JavaCC
Select Project (my-java-cc-example)
popup menu Properties

Left : Project Natures
Right : Click Button Add...
    Confirm Window, Click Button `OK`    


Select Nature Window ,
Select JavaCC Nature
Click Button OK

Left: JavaCC
Right: Tab Javacc options

JDK_VERSION: 17
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY: MyJavaCCExampleMaven/src/main/java

(I change output directory to src/main/java)
Click Button Apply and Close

JavaCC options change window ,
Click Button Yes

Add Source Folder
Select Project (my-java-cc-example)
popup menu New -> Source Folder

Click Button Browse...
Select src/main/jj
Click Button OK

Folder name: src/main/jj
Click Button Finish

Now, you can see src/main/jj icon is Source Folder style.

Add JavaCC Console View
Menu Window -> Show View -> Other...

JavaCC -> JavaCC Console
Click Button Open

Add Console View
Menu Window -> Show View -> Console

Manual Compile jj file
Select calculator.jj
Popup Menu Compile with JavaCC | JJTree | JTB

You can find src/main/java show some java files.
You can also edit calculator.jj directly, and then JavaCC will automatically compile it, and then output the corresponding .java file to the src/main/java directory. It will do this automatically. No need to execute it manually. JavaCC compilation.

Select Calculator.java
popup menu Run As -> Java Application

mouse click console view window
input 11 + 22 then press Enter Key.
get result: 33.0


I deleted my previous comment as I now see that you really meant to create only a folder,  not a project, without eclipse, outside of the workspace to be imported later.

Great! It works! Thanks a lot! I had searched the net for examples to do it with maven, but the pom's I found were much more complicated, and, didn't work (repository not found, mostly, but other errors, too).

Still doesn't work for my old project, but that must be a local quirk I have to find&fix for myself. In doubt, I'll copy all the code of the old project to the new, working, one. Again, thanks a lot!

This maven project example uses the JavaCC Eclipse Plugin based on your requirements. There are other examples on the Internet that use the JavaCC Maven Plugin to convert jj to java when Maven is executed. The usage methods and spirit of the two are different.
