comparing eclipse project settings systemattically
My question is: how I can systematically compare the settings of two eclipse projects?
Background: I have two projects in eclipse, both using JavaCC. When I add maven nature to one of them, JavaCC doesn't work any more. When I remove maven nature, the once-has-been maven project seems spoiled, JavaCC still does not work.
So I need a systematical method to find what the difference is between these projects.

You can run diff on the configuration files, located in the .settings directory in the project folder.
So you run
diff -r NewProject/.settings OldProject/.settings
That will show all differences between the config of NewProject and OldProject
(There is also a .classpath so also do a:
diff -r NewProject/.classpath OldProject/classpath
Because this is just doing a text diff, it might be difficult to read, but it should at least give you a hint.
Where NewProjecet and OldProjcet is the name of the old/new project folder.

That's what I was looking for, but I didn't expect the difference being in only one or two files. And I did not ask for an easy way, just for a systematical one.

.settings is a folder, now a file. There are many files inside it which is why you should run diff -r to compare 2 folders. (Or you can compare each file on it's own).

Folder or file, it's just one place. And in my special case, there is an option "org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.methodParameters=do not generate", and in the same folder there is also a file "org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs" that looks like eclipse hasn't removed it together with the maven-nature.

@GyroGearloose Have you verified whether it is caused by the different org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs settings files. Be aware that you can diff and edit those files inside of Eclipse. If you make changes to this file outside of Eclipse, you have to do a Refresh (F5) in Eclipse.

@howlger Yes, I have checked all files I have found based on the accepted answer. There were a lot of differences that were not reverted when "removing" the maven nature, albeit the two projects were created in exactly the same way, with the only difference that one had a "holiday" as maven project. It finally worked again after I checked .classpath (which I had suspected the least), found and removed maven references. I frequently work with emacsclient outside of eclipse, so F5 is the first thing I do after changes by habit.
